# Why are most natural phenomena described using differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I noticed that most equations that I've encountered in physics and engineering classes are formulated as differential equations. Some examples I can think of on top of my head are Newton's 2nd law, the wave equation, Maxwell's equations, etc. My question is, what's so special about differential equations that make them the optimal tool to model natural phenomena?

Comment: Because differential equations were developed to model physical phenomena...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the point is that physical systems are acted on by certain forces, causing gradual change in their state, and the response depends only on the state of the system at the current time: thus the rates of change of the system variables (positions
and velocities in mechanics) are functions of those variables.  That is exactly what a differential equation is (with time as the independent variable).

Comment: I've upvoted this answer.  But, why differential equations as opposed to differential inequalities?

Answer (score 1):

We can make progress with many differential equations.  We rarely ask about the lengths of curves because they don't have nice answers.